# Writing a ZIP on the fly?

Tags: java, zip

At the moment I am tracing a load of files that come into my system to a directory. The issue is that I am running out of iNodes (the number of files I can store). For "replay" reasons (there are other reasons too), I would like the files to be separate files, so I can't just write to one file.

I am wondering whether I can replace this with code that will write the files to a ZIP on the fly. However, my concern is - what happens if the JVM crashes during procesing for whatever reason, do will I end up with a corrupt ZIP file? Or is there a way that I can ensure that the ZIP is valid after every "write"?

Comment: You say "a load of files that come into my system to a directory", then "I can't just write to one file" -- it isn't clear whether these files are put in the directory by something outside your program, or whether you are putting them there.  Certainly you can write them to a zipfile, and certainly you can guard against corruption with some amount of processing time, reduced risk, and programming trouble.  But there might be a solution that doesn't involve that; to know, we'd have to know more about how the files are created and what you're trying to do with them.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a database.

Comment: My process is writing these files to a folder right now. Everytime the process receives a new file, it "traces it" (writes it) to a folder.